# Reconnect if connection fails using R

Tags: r

I have written small function but somehow does not work as expected.

I have connection to server and sometime the server is down so I cannot connect. The script is running in batch so I have to have it automatized.

The script should run the `conn <- function(..)` successfully (it means no error message) if not `restart/re-check` and restart again in approx. 1min time. This should run in loop until connection is established something like 12 hours. (approx.). The connection should be assigned to `conn` object so the object must return successful connection. (something like `<Connection established, @ 20180522 20:43:41 CET>`

The function which does not work is here:

```
connect <- function(c) { message(paste("remaining run", c)); 
                     withRestarts(err <- tryCatch({ conn <- server.coonect(settings...) }, 
                     error=function(e) { invokeRestart("reconnect") }), reconnect = function() { message("re-connecting"); 
                     stopifnot(c > 0); for(i in 1:10) { Sys.sleep(6); cat(i) }; connect(c-1) }) }

connect(1000) # with approx. 1min sleep we get here over 12 hours running..
```

So the question is what is wrong and how to rewrite the function such it runs as expected. Thanks.

**EDIT**

It seems that the function should be:

```
connect <- function(c) { message(paste("remaining run", c)); 
                 withRestarts(err <- tryCatch({ server.coonect(settings...) }, 
                 error=function(e) { invokeRestart("reconnect") }), reconnect = function() { message("re-connecting"); 
                 stopifnot(c > 0); for(i in 1:10) { Sys.sleep(6); cat(i) } }) }

conn <- connect(1000)
```

**EDIT 2**

*Here is comment for the above function I have tested:*

I have tested the EDIT function by simulating the connection by first running the function without internet connection (now the function checks every 1:10 o 6sec, and after the function is running I connect to the internet, now I expect the function in next iteration pics up and connects to server if available...) what happens is that the function does not pick up the later possibility to connect...

Comment: It is hard for me to understand your code completely but the final line of your function definition includes `connect(c-1)`, are you trying to use the function connect with its own definition?

Comment: @bmrn: you are right, in fact the connect(c-1) is redundant and should be definitely not inside the calling function...

Comment: Is your intention just to try to connect until a successful connection is established or do you also want to reconnect in case the connection is lost again during further processing steps (which would require a idempotent way of restarting the processing)?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. No check and reconnect if connection is lost is not needed however this is something actually I would expect this function does. I have tested the EDIT function by simulating the connection by first running the function without internet connection (now the function checks every 1:10 o 6sec, and after the function is running I connect to the internet, now I expect the function in next iteration pics up and connects to server if available...) what happens is that the function does not pick up the later possibility to connect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to loop over the connection establishment this will work:

```
# simulate an instable connection
server.connect <- function(...) {
  if (round(as.numeric(Sys.time())) %% 10 != 0) # about 90 % failed connections
    stop("Connection error")
  return(TRUE)  # success
}

connect <- function(attempts = 1, sleep.seconds = 6) {
  for (i in 1:attempts) {
    res <- try(server.connect("my connection string"), silent = TRUE)
    if (!("try-error" %in% class(res))) {
      print("Connected...")
      return(res)
    }
    print(paste0("Attempt #", i, " failed"))
    Sys.sleep(sleep.seconds)
  }
  stop("Maximum number of connection attempts exceeded")
}

con <- connect(attempts = 10, sleep = 1)
```

Example execution log:

```
[1] "Attempt #1 failed"
[1] "Attempt #2 failed"
[1] "Attempt #3 failed"
[1] "Attempt #4 failed"
[1] "Attempt #5 failed"
[1] "Attempt #6 failed"
[1] "Connected..."
```